# Add core data entry and segue at the same time

Tags: ios, core-data, uistoryboardsegue

In my tableView I have a button on the nav bar to add a new core data entry. This works fine and the new entry is added to core data and at the top of the tableView. Then if I select the entry (or any entry) in the tableView, I have a seque that transitions to a new view controller showing the details of that core data item. That works fine too.

But I'd like to change how I add entries. I'd like to push the same button in the nav bar and I'd still like the new entry added to the table. But at the same time I want to transition to the detail view controller AND show the just created values for the entry I just made.

As you can see from the code below, the seque to view game details simply grabs the row that was selected and passes it to the detail view controller. In my prepareForAddGameDetailSegue I tried to cheat by just setting the indexPath to 0 for the newly created entry where the new entry is inserted. That doesn't work and I have a feeling it's because my fetchedResultsController isn't updated before the transition.

So when the detail view controller loads values for the newly created game are null. But if I go back to the tableView and then select the row where that new game was just inserted, it'll transition fine and the details will all show.

Anyone help on what step I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Here are the segue handlers:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showGameDetails"]) {
        [self prepareForGameDetailSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender];
        return;
    }

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addGameDetails"]) {
        [self prepareForAddGameDetailSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender];
        return;
    }
}

- (void)prepareForGameDetailSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    Game *SelectedGame = (Game *)[[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        //pass the selected game to the new view controller
    GameDetailViewController *detailViewController = (GameDetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    detailViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Game Details"];
    detailViewController.game = SelectedGame;
    [detailViewController updateInterface];
}

- (void)prepareForAddGameDetailSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender {

    [self addGame];

    Game *newGame = (Game *)[[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:0];

    GameDetailViewController *detailViewController = (GameDetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    detailViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"New Game"];
    detailViewController.game = newGame;
    [detailViewController updateInterface];

}
```

Here's the addGame method:

```
-(void)addGame {

    Game *newGame = (Game *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Game"
                                                          inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    newGame.gameDate = today;
    newGame.points = 600;
    newGame.seconds = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error in adding a new game %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the signature of `-(void)addGame` to `-(Game*)addGame` and return the newly saved game.
use the object returned to load your detail view.
later, in the return segue, find the index of the newly inserted object and select it.
You can use: `- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForObject:` method of the FRC to get the IndexPath.

Comment: Nice! You are correct, just return newGame from the addGame method. Then I just passed it with `detailViewController.game = [self addGame];` Didn't need to grab it's indexPath.